# Compiling from source error

Tags: ros, build-from-source, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently reinstalling ROS, exactly the way i did before this install. Basically just following [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) to the letter. Somehow, this is not working for me at the moment.

When the building process arrives at the part where it compiles (or 'rosmakes') ros_comm it halts, due to an error. Something is going wrong with the paths.

```
CMake Error at /home/erik/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:110 (message):
[rosbuild] rospack found package "cpp_common" at "", but the current
directory is "/home/erik/ros/ros_comm/test/test_crosspackage".  You 
should double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the
correct precedence order. Call Stack (most recent call first): /home/erik/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:180 (_rosbuild_check_package_location) CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosbuild_init).
```

So clearly something is going wrong filling out the actual path: `rospack found package "cpp_common" at ""`

I checked ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, but i wouldn't know what the correct order would be. Here it is (it scrolls a long way right).

```
robot_model_tutorials:visualization_tutorials:geometry_tutorials:common_tutorials:ros_tutorials:documentation:geometry_experimental:robot_model_visualization:geometry_visualization:diagnostics_monitors:executive_smach_visualization:visualization:slam_gmapping:navigation:vision_opencv:laser_pipeline:image_pipeline:image_transport_plugins:perception_pcl:image_common:rx:visualization_common:physics_ode:stage:simulator_gazebo:simulator_stage:xacro:executive_smach:robot_model:assimp:pluginlib:orocos_kinematics_dynamics:nodelet_core:geometry:bullet:filters:eigen:driver_common:diagnostics:common:common_msgs:bond_core:common_rosdeps:ros_comm:ros
```

Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong here? I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04LTS (32bits).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29376/compiling-from-source-error/) by [Erik_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1614/erik_s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug (my fault) in rosinstall 0.6.2

Make sure to update rosinstall by either running
sudo pip install -U rosinstall

or

sudo easy_install -U rosinstall vcstools

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erik_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1614/erik_s/) on 2012-03-11**:
Thanks! Unfortunately i can't test it now, http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosinstall/ is offline.

**Comment by [Erik_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1614/erik_s/) on 2012-03-14**:
It works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having the same problem yesterday. I finally got it working by changing the setup.sh file in the ros folder to an older version I still had (see below). But this is not really a proper solution.

```
#!/bin/sh
# THIS IS A FILE AUTO-GENERATED BY rosinstall
# IT IS UNLIKELY YOU WANT TO EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND
# IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE ROS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
# USE THE rosinstall TOOL INSTEAD.
# see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall
export ROS_ROOT=/home/erik/ros/ros
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src:$PYTHONPATH
if [ ! "$ROS_MASTER_URI" ] ; then export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 ; fi
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/erik/ros/robot_model_tutorials:/home/erik/ros/visualization_tutorials:/home/erik/ros/geometry_tutorials:/home/erik/ros/common_tutorials:/home/erik/ros/ros_tutorials:/home/erik/ros/documentation:/home/erik/ros/geometry_experimental:/home/erik/ros/robot_model_visualization:/home/erik/ros/geometry_visualization:/home/erik/ros/diagnostics_monitors:/home/erik/ros/executive_smach_visualization:/home/erik/ros/visualization:/home/erik/ros/slam_gmapping:/home/erik/ros/navigation:/home/erik/ros/vision_opencv:/home/erik/ros/laser_pipeline:/home/erik/ros/image_pipeline:/home/erik/ros/image_transport_plugins:/home/erik/ros/perception_pcl_electric_unstable:/home/erik/ros/image_common:/home/erik/ros/rx:/home/erik/ros/visualization_common:/home/erik/ros/physics_ode:/home/erik/ros/stage:/home/erik/ros/simulator_gazebo:/home/erik/ros/simulator_stage:/home/erik/ros/xacro:/home/erik/ros/executive_smach:/home/erik/ros/robot_model:/home/erik/ros/assimp:/home/erik/ros/pluginlib:/home/erik/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics:/home/erik/ros/nodelet_core:/home/erik/ros/geometry:/home/erik/ros/bullet:/home/erik/ros/filters:/home/erik/ros/eigen:/home/erik/ros/driver_common:/home/erik/ros/diagnostics:/home/erik/ros/common:/home/erik/ros/common_msgs:/home/erik/ros/bond_core:/home/erik/ros/common_rosdeps:/home/erik/ros/ros_comm
export ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/erik/ros
```

---

Originally posted by [cfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1782/cfo/) with karma: 11 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1